# Extract last value from vector in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one data set.This data set  contain two columns first is column with ID and second is with VALUE.You can see code and table below :

```
DATA_TEST <- data.frame(
  ID = c("03740270423222","03740270423222","03740270423222","03740270423222","01380926325248","01380926325248","01380926325248"),
  VALUE = c("100","200","300","200","300","200","300"))
```

[image]

But here in table there are a lot of duplicate, so my intention is only to extract last value separably by each ID so final result should be like in table below:

[image]

So can anybody help me how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base` R solution with `aggregate()` and `tail()`

```
aggregate(VALUE~ ID, DATA_TEST, tail, 1)

#               ID VALUE
# 1 01380926325248   300
# 2 03740270423222   200
```

---

or by `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
```

***option 1:*** *`summarise()` + `last()`*

```
DATA_TEST %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(VALUE = last(VALUE))
```

***option 2:*** *`slice_tail() <=> slice(n())`*

```
DATA_TEST %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_tail()
```

Answer (score 1):

In data.table:

```
DATA_TEST<-data.frame(
  ID=c("03740270423222","03740270423222","03740270423222","03740270423222","01380926325248","01380926325248","01380926325248"),
  VALUE=c("100","200","300","200","300","200","300")
)

library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(DATA_TEST)

DT[, .(VALUE = last(VALUE)), by = ID]

               ID VALUE
1: 03740270423222   200
2: 01380926325248   300
```